# Java cucumber IllegalArgumentException inconsistencies in path

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber

I am using Cucumber for the first time and I am facing a few problems while running the tests. My project structure is as it follows:

claim-resolution-service -> src -> test -> java -> gradle.cucumber (where I keep my testing classes)

claim-resolution-service -> src -> test -> resources -> gradle.cucumber (where I keep my feature files)

I have this in my gradle:

```
configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testRuntime
    }
}

task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'gradle.cucumber', 'src/test/resources/']
        }
    }
}
```

And my test class has these arguments:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = "pretty", features = "claim-resolution-service/src/test/resources/gradle.cucumber")
```

With the scenario described above, when I run `gradle test` and `gradle cucumber` everything builds successfully. But when I try to run the test class I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: claim-resolution-service/claim-resolution-service/src/test/resources/gradle.cucumber
```

Which made sense to me, so I decided to remove the `claim-resolution-service` from the features path I have inside my test class. Running the test from the test class and `gradle cucumber` worked but `gradle test` failed with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` as well.

I think there's some inconsistencies with my project but I was not able to find out and fix them. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try `features = "classpath:gradle.feature"` and make sure you rename the `cucumber` file to `feature` file.

Comment: It worked, thanks! gradle.cucumber is the directory that contains the feature and the testing files.